# Access nested JSON with month numbers

Tags: javascript, json, variables

i got an json file with monthly values. i need to access these. I am not able to archive this. Maybe i just make an mistake.

```
{"sales":
  {
    "total_sales":"999.99",
    "totals":
       {
         "2020-10-01":
             {
               "sales":"9.99",
             }
       }
  }
}
```

How can i get the value from the second "sales" with 9.99?

I use JS to get the total_sales. This works.

I really need you help for this.

---

For more clearence:
The JSON-File is an original from Woocommerce.

I implement the Json with the original API and need the sales for every month.

I already tried it with Object.keys but it does not work. i only get the (2020-01-01) Names but not the nested values.

Here is the information about the original JSON File:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/blob/master/source/includes/v2/_reports.md

Bad thing is the date string as key.

Maybe there is a tricky way to archive the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @JaredSmith - this appears to be another "I have a terrible data structure" help me search it pls. The OP's issue is probably the date string-as-key thing.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes, probably. That is (obliquely) covered in the linked dupe though, so...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: The format is an woocommerce original JSOn File. So i dont know how to get the numbers Variable to catch the sub values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's say you have data with the variable name salesReport like this:

```
{
  "sales": {
    "totals": {
      "2015-01-18": {
        "sales": "-17.00",
      },
      "2015-01-21": {
        "sales": "597.10",
      },
      "2015-02-18": {
        "sales": "32.00",
      },
      "2015-03-12": {
        "sales": "22.00",
      },
    },
  }
}
```

Then you want to access the sales.totals data for each date without having to know the key details. Furthermore, if you need to store the key (in this case the date) along with their respective values then you can convert them into entries first using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) as in the following code:

```
const salesReportTotalsEntries = Object.entries(salesReport.sales.totals);
```

Then you can access the sales data on each date using

```
salesReportTotalsEntries[0][1].sales
salesReportTotalsEntries[1][1].sales
```

And the last step is that you can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum each totals sales data based on the data for each month. Here's the complete code:

```js
const salesReport = {
  "sales": {
    "totals": {
      "2015-01-18": {
        "sales": "-17.00",
      },
      "2015-01-21": {
        "sales": "597.10",
      },
      "2015-02-18": {
        "sales": "32.00",
      },
      "2015-03-12": {
        "sales": "22.00",
      },
    },
  }
};

const salesReportTotalsEntries = Object.entries(salesReport.sales.totals);
const salesReportTotalsByMonths = salesReportTotalsEntries.reduce((a, v) => {
  const currentMonth = v[0].split('-')[1];
  if (!a[currentMonth]) {
    a[currentMonth] = Number(v[1].sales);
    return a;
  }
  a[currentMonth] += Number(v[1].sales);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(`Total Sales Report in January is ${salesReportTotalsByMonths['01']}`);
console.log(`Total Sales Report in February is ${salesReportTotalsByMonths['02']}`);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much.
Is there a way to replace the dot for a comma?
I already tried replace(".",","). But its not working and throws an error.

Comment: Hi @Oliver don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if this answer has solved your problem :)